# android set font size of tab

Tags: android, tabs

i have an android app with a tab activity.
the font size is to large, because the last 1 - 2 letters will be cut.
how can i set my font size of these tabs?

i add my tabs to the tab activity like this:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1");

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2");

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3");


        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this style:

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i add your code to my style.xml and add       android:theme="@style/MineCustomTabText" to the <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout tag. apps crashed with this error: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class TextView

Comment: use android:style="@style/MineCustomTabText" instead

Comment: then i get Error:(34) No resource identifier found for attribute 'style' in package 'android'